# How to capture and send azure chatbot conversation to mail

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot

I'm developing a chatbot with azure QnA maker and I need to capture the data of the session and conversation and then send it all to the user's email. I was capturing the data through a blob storage and there the information is stored through several JSON, but I still can't capture all the information to automatically send it by mail. Is there a tool to capture this information? or Do you know of any documentation that I can follow?

Thank you for your help!

[Blob storage images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwXmn.png)
[Blob storage images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrOQF.png)

Comment: What kind of info are you capturing? What's missing? There's no tool for this, but if you've got the data in an Azure Blob, you can use whatever solution you would like to send email.

Comment: Just write an Azure Function or something that triggers when new blobs are added. Write a bit of code formatting the JSON to something readable and use an email client to send the email.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering, I am currently saving the data in this way in a blob storage a folder is created with a specific Id which inside integrates several JSON which belong to each option that the user selects in the chatbot and Im trying to unify all the JSON and convert them to text, I also want to take the user's email to send him all the information.

Comment: As the other user suggested, creating an Azure Function that triggers when a new blob is created and having that function send the email is a viable solution. You would collect the information from the user and write it to the blob, then the function would take it from there.